# MvcContrib - How to get Area into MenuBuilder ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I am using MenuBuilder with code like this:

```
        public static MenuItem MainMenu(UrlHelper url)
    {
        Menu.DefaultIconDirectory = url.Content("~/Public/Images/");
        Menu.DefaultDisabledClass = "disabled";
        Menu.DefaultSelectedClass = "current";

        return Menu.Begin(
                    Menu.Items("",
                        Menu.Action<HomeController>(p => p.Index(), "Home")
                    ),
                    Menu.Items("",
                        Menu.Secure<HomeController>(p => p.About(), "About")
                    ),
                    Menu.Items("",
                        Menu.Action<RegulationController>(p => p.Index(null), "Compliance")
                    )/* This is in the Compliance area */
                    ).SetListClass("menu");
    }
```

But I am also using MvcContib Areas and in the code above the final menu item is in an 'Area' called 'Compliance'.

(There are two other areas in the Mvc application and the first in the list of registered areas is called 'Legislation')

What happens is the following:

When a page is rendered (I am using the standard WebFormsViewEngine) the Urls are all rendered using the 'Legislation' area!!?

E.g. http://localhost:1337/Legislation/Home or http://localhost:1337/Legislation/Home/About

and finally http://localhost:1337/Legislation/Regulation

The first two links should not pick up the 'Legislation' area. The last menu item should be in the 'Compliance' area.

How do I prevent the erroneous Area (Legislation) being rendered on the first two links?

How do I get the MenuBuilder markup in the Site.Master to accept an 'area' attribute or get it picked up automatically from the Controller for each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MvcContrib MenuBuilder does not play well with Areas. In the end I took the Areas out and the problem went away.

However, I recognise there may have been some other issue in the Mvc application which may indeed have been related to the older (beta?) version of Mvc dll that MvcContrib was referencing.

**So for anyone that comes across this it may indeed be a none issue.**